# Remove the query parameters that are appended while redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have WordPress .htaccess file, here it is how it looks.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# the following three lines will work for all subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule . "http://www.example.net/" [R=301,L]

# the following two lines will redirect non-www to www version of the domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.net/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Wordfence WAF

<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

I want to redirect my subdomain to the main domain.

The problem is if I hit like, `subdomain.example.net/anystring` it gets successfully redirected to `example.net`

But, if I hit like, `subdomain.example.net/anystring?anytext` it gets successfully redirected to `example.net?anytext`

so here `?anytext` is appended, I need to remove anything that is appended to `subdomain.example.net`

I have tried a couple of things but was unsuccessful.

I would request your help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?` to prevent query string from being appended to replacement url ,so change these two lines in code :

```
RewriteRule . "http://www.example.net/" [R=301,L]
```

by this :

```
RewriteRule . "http://www.example.net/?" [R=301,L]
```

and this line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.net/$1" [R=301,L]
```

by this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.net/$1?" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, this solved the problem, but there is one more thing, if the URL is something like `subdomain.example.net/anytext?d` it redirects to `example.net?d`

Comment: change this line RewriteRule . "http://www.example.net/?" [R=301,L] to this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.net/$1?" [R=301,L]

Comment: Okay, thanks, and can you please help me on how can I redirect `http://www.exaple.com/?extratext=1` to `http://www.example.com/`